# tkinter inserting from numpy to a listbox

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

alright so, i pulled a database and made my self a txt file

i read the text file with panda read csv and i searched for a word inside of it with this code:

```
row , col = np.where(data == word)
print(data.loc[row])
```

lets say i serach for mulan
it prints it like this:

```
 TITLE  YEAR       IMDB

1  Mulan  2020  tt4566758
```

now i want this to be inserted to a listbox
(code):

```
row , col = np.where(data == word)
list1.insert(END,data.loc[row])
```

but it is shown like this, and not the way the dataframe looks:
[image: here is the problem]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused with the code you displayed but I would recommend you store the data as a dictionary in a .json file and search that instead of using a numpy array. Its quite easy with python.

edit: You requested an example.

Here is an example .json file

```
{
    "Movies": [
                {
                "Name": "Mulan"
                "Year": "2020"
                "Imdb": "t5000"
                },
                {
                "Name": "The lion king"
                "Year": "2005"
                "Imdb": "t3576"
                }
            ]
}
```

First you import json

```
import json
```

You then open the data with

```
file = open("filename",r)
```

Then you load the data into a dictonary, this is called deserialization.

```
data = json.load(file)
```

Finally you iterate and search through the data with

```
cnt = 0
found = 0
for movie in data["Movies"]:
    if movie["Name"] == "The lion king":
        found = cnt
    cnt += 1

row = data["Movies"][found]
```

If the data is found, it is saved to the variable row.

Now for the listbox the code is simple

```
listRow = row["Name"] + "    " + row["Year"] + "    " + row["Imdb"]
Lb = Listbox(Tk())
Lb.insert(1, "NAME    YEAR    IMDB")
Lb.insert(2, listRow)
```

You can adjust the spacing between NAME, YEAR and IMDB as well as in listRow as needed.

I tried to make this as simple as possible on purpose.

Comment: how do i search a key word in json file? and then how to display it properly?

Comment: the thing is i want it to be display as a dataframe, when i prin tit normally its being printed nice and organized, but when i insert it to a listbox it gets ruined

Comment: first save the data to a variable in the form of a string. Then you can say somevariable = data.json()["keyword"]["SubKeyword"]. Using a json file is neater when for creating a data hierarchy. The problem with your list box is that the box thinks the labels are part of the data and removes the line break. youll have to make the titles one row and the data another. @comingfall

Comment: can you make me an example? of the search and insert?